# Where are logs of git-daemon saved? (Git on windows using Cygwin)

Tags: git, git-daemon

I am running git-daemon as a windows service. (using Create Process)
The command used in service is:

```
git daemon --reuseaddr --base-path=/data/test_work/ --export-all \
    --verbose --enable=receive-pack
```

Where do I see the logs of `git daemon`?

Note: there is no file at `/var/logs`.

Comment: I would like to know that too, did you find where are the logs?

Comment: I moved ahead and did not use this atall. So didnt bother finding a solution later.
I guess we have to manually redirect the log into a file, both input and error stream. I couldn't think of anything now.

Comment: All right, I understood. Thank you for answering!

Comment: More than 3 years later, there is a new option with Git 2.17: see [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48977619/6309).

Answer (score 1):

If you still need and want to do it, I have found a way to do that: just create a bash script with execution permissions and tell the daemon to log its stuff into one or two files (if you want to log stderr separately):

```
#!/bin/bash

# Git daemon launchd startup command.

GIT_RO_USER="git-ro" # The user which has read only access to the repositories.

GIT_REP_BASE_PATH="/path/to/GitRepositories" # The repositories base path.

GIT_LOG_FILE="/var/log/git.log" # The git daemon log file. The user which runs the script must have the right write permissions

/path/to/git daemon --reuseaddr --verbose --user=$GIT_RO_USER --base-path=$GIT_REP_BASE_PATH $GIT_REP_BASE_PATH >> $GIT_LOG_FILE 2>&1

# Or if you like to keep the error log separated, uncomment the following lines and comment the previous one:
#GIT_ERR_LOG_FILE="/var/log/git_err.log" # The error log file
#/path/to/git daemon --reuseaddr --verbose --user=$GIT_RO_USER --base-path=$GIT_REP_BASE_PATH $GIT_REP_BASE_PATH >> $GIT_LOG_FILE 2>> $GIT_ERR_LOG_FILE
```

Where `/path/to/git` is the path to the git command. I use it with `launchd` on my OS X machine cause I have noticed that you can't setup `StandardOutPath` and `StandardErrorPath` keys for the daemon using a .plist file.

Hope it helps you too!

Comment: One question! If its for more than 3-4 people and will be your mode of sharing for a longer time, do consider sharing over ssh. I dont like daemon that much.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, this is just for read only repositories, you know maybe you have many teams where each team works on a project: each team uses SSH to access and push on its own project but each one can clone a project on which another team is working on using `git://`, in order to have just a bit of transparency in the company. But anyway, I agree with you, SSH is the right way to go if you need to grant write access to the repo too. :)

Comment: Even in my architecture everyone has visibility to others repositories. I manage write permission at folder level. A person is allowed to access the system over ssh but he cant write to a repository unless it is shared at file level.
That way write access is restricted to people I want and everyone else has read only access.

Comment: I didn't understand you, `A person is allowed to access the system over ssh but he cant write to a repository unless it is shared at file level`, do you mean that you create a shared repo, as with `git init --bare --shared`, and then you add the users with push access to the group which has write access to the repo, or something like that?

Comment: Sorry for late response. Yes! I do exactly that!

Answer (score 1):

> Where do I see the logs of git daemon?

Git 2.17 (Q1 2018) can help, since the log from "`git daemon`" can be redirected with a new option; one relevant use case is to send the log to standard error (instead of syslog) when running it from `inetd`.

See [commit 0c591ca](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0c591cacba00a36af797fa3b6c4a4f12d342be86) (04 Feb 2018) by [Lucas Werkmeister (`lucaswerkmeister`)](https://github.com/lucaswerkmeister).
Helped-by: [Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason (`avar`)](https://github.com/avar), [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster), and [Eric Sunshine (`sunshineco`)](https://github.com/sunshineco).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit c2bd43d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c2bd43d66dab958d72bee58d319df55600158f2e), 21 Feb 2018)</sup>

> ### `daemon`: add `--log-destination=(stderr|syslog|none)`
>
> This new option can be used to override the implicit `--syslog` of `--inetd`, or to disable all logging. (While `--detach` also implies `--syslog`, `--log-destination=stderr` with `--detach` is useless since `--detach` disassociates the process from the original stderr.) `--syslog` is retained as an alias for `--log-destination=syslog`.
>
> `--log-destination` always overrides implicit `--syslog` regardless of
>   option order.
>   This is different than the “last one wins” logic that
>   applies to some implicit options elsewhere in Git, but should hopefully
>   be less confusing.
>   (I also don’t know if *all* implicit options in Git follow “last one wins”.)
>
> The combination of `--inetd` with `--log-destination=stderr` is useful, for
>   instance, when running `git daemon` as an instanced `systemd` service
>   (with associated socket unit).
>   In this case, log messages sent via `syslog` are received by the journal daemon, but run the risk of being processed at a time when the `git daemon` process has already exited (especially if the process was very short-lived, e.g. due to client error), so that the journal daemon can no longer read its `cgroup` and
>   attach the message to the correct `systemd` unit (see [systemd/systemd issue 2913](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/2913)). Logging to `stderr` instead can solve this problem, because `systemd` can connect `stderr` directly to the journal daemon, which then already
>   knows which unit is associated with this stream.

---

Git 2.18 (Q2 2018) make things more robust, since the recent introduction of "`--log-destination`" option to "`git daemon`" did not work well when the daemon was run under "`--inetd`" mode.

> ### `daemon.c`: fix condition for redirecting `stderr`
>
> Since the `--log-destination` option was added in [0c591ca](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0c591cacba00a36af797fa3b6c4a4f12d342be86) ("daemon: add
>   `--log-destination=(stderr|syslog|none)`", 2018-02-04, Git 2.17) with the explicit goal of allowing logging to `stderr` when running in `inetd` mode, we should not always redirect `stderr` to `/dev/null` in inetd mode, but rather only when `stderr` is not being used for logging.